# Snowflake SQL Age Calculations

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table containing registration details for children aged 0-18.
I am trying to create a column (titled AGE_YRS_MOS) that shows the age at registration in 'x' years if a child is older than 1, or in 'x' months if a child is less than 1. I also have a system calculated 'age' column that I am comparing my calculated column to.

The case when statement I am using is giving me strange values, with examples in the table below:

```
CASE WHEN age >=1 THEN concat(to_varchar(datediff(year,birth_date, reg_date)),' yrs ')
     WHEN age <1 THEN concat(to_varchar(datediff(year, birth_date, reg_date)*12), ' months')
END AS AGE_YRS_MOS,
```

| Age | AGE_YRS_MOS |
| --- | --- |
| 17 | 18 yrs |
| 8 | 9 yrs |
| 0.20 | 0 months |
| 0.42 | 0 months |
| 0.56 | 12 months |

It appears that datediff is rounding up some year values, and also miscalculating all month values.

The expected output would be, for example a child with a birthdate of 04/15/2013 and registration date of 10/1/2021, or an infant with a birthdate of 08/01/2021 and registration date of 10/15/2021:

| Age | AGE_YRS_MOS |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 8 yrs |
| 0.20 | 2 months |

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: This is explained in the USAGE section of the DATEDIFF function documentation. If you take the year part it takes just the year (with no rounding) - so anything less than 12 months = 0 years. So multiplying zero by 12 still gives zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate age by months you need to pass `month` as date part to `datediff()` :

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN age >=1 THEN concat(to_varchar(datediff(year,birth_date, reg_date)),' yrs')
          WHEN age < 1 THEN concat(to_varchar(datediff(month, birth_date, reg_date)), ' months')
     END AS AGE_YRS_MOS
FROM mytable;
```